# Digest not occuring with a cached $http response

Tags: angularjs

Using angularjs 1.2.21

When I don't use the cache with $http, there is clearly a digest cycle between the GET and the asynchronous response, since a visual element is correctly updated in my page after a change to a variable that is interpolated in the view.
But when I set cache to true, and the data comes from the cache, my view stops to be updated, meaning that no digest occured.

The angularjs doc states that even when the data comes from the cache, the response is asynchronous. But it says nothing about the digest cycle.

> Note that even if the response is served from cache, delivery of the data is asynchronous in the same way that real requests are.

To workaround this, I need to put the $http call in a $timeout(func,0).

So, in your opinion, is it a bug or is it as designed?

**Update**: @PSL [I forked your plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PJbYn4YExXkQOhSayoLs?p=preview) to show you how to reproduce it. Run it. You will see that the "load in progress" message appear the first time you hit the button, then it won't appear anymore. Remove the cache and it will appear everytime. Basically I'm trying to alter the view just during the Get call and restore it when it's finished.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.22"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p ng-show="load">Load in progress</p>
    <p>{{i}}</p>
    <button ng-click="refresh()">Refresh</button>
  </body>

</html>



var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.i=0;
  $scope.load = false;

  $scope.refresh = function(){
    $scope.load = true;
  $http.get('test.json', {cache:true}).success(function(resp){
    $scope.i++;
    $scope.name = resp;
    $scope.load = false;
  });
  }
});
```

**Update 2**: I don't think I will be able to reproduce it here because my actual code is more complex. In fact, modifying the load variable is captured by another directive (that binds to it) which will reset a 3rd party jquery module. When using caching, the jquery module does not always reset correctly which would tend to show that getting the response is so fast that the binding does not reach the module that watches it...

Comment: Works fine for me.. http://plnkr.co/edit/lRoHIJ?p=preview Your problem could be elsewhere. Can you replicate it?

Comment: @PSL Thanks. Updated my question to show you.

Comment: Cool. Can you please paste the forked url?

Comment: @PSL sorry I missed the fork url, now I see. Here is the code and my plunkr

Comment: Not really that is because it happens too fast (since there is no network request) and mostly both the scope changes get updated in the same digest cycle.. you don't see the change... Just put a time out and you will see the change when there is a delay. http://plnkr.co/edit/0hSxmW?p=preview

Comment: your setTimeout breaks the test because we leave the Refresh handler and a digest will take place before the call to Get. About the speed which would prevent to see the message, I'm not sure...

Comment: That is exactly my point was... Since there is no real request takes place and hence the latency the updates happens during the same digest cycle, since the data is picked up from the cache and it is not pushed to async queue.. It is not the issue of digest cycle not being executed when the cache is enabled... if that was the case you won't even see the data change reflected.  http://plnkr.co/edit/tx4Aod?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the angular `done()` function on github below, I think it's a bug.
(**EDIT** @PSL thinks it's not a bug).

However what is still true is that, assuming no errors occur in this method, there is no way to avoid a scope.apply() - other than `$apply.$$phase` being truthy.

Perhaps your best bet is to use the `useApplyAsync` flag to ensure that it works.

Done function here:

```
 function done(status, response, headersString, statusText) {
    if (cache) {
      if (isSuccess(status)) {
        cache.put(url, [status, response, parseHeaders(headersString), statusText]);
      } else {
        // remove promise from the cache
        cache.remove(url);
      }
    }

    function resolveHttpPromise() {
      resolvePromise(response, status, headersString, statusText);
    }

    if (useApplyAsync) {
      $rootScope.$applyAsync(resolveHttpPromise);
    } else {
      resolveHttpPromise();
      if (!$rootScope.$$phase) $rootScope.$apply();
    }
  }
```

Actually, on the git 1.2.x branch, `useApplyAsync` is not available. Can you upgrade to the latest version?

The old done function:

```
function done(status, response, headersString, statusText) {
    if (cache) {
      if (isSuccess(status)) {
        cache.put(url, [status, response, parseHeaders(headersString), statusText]);
      } else {
        // remove promise from the cache
        cache.remove(url);
      }
    }

    resolvePromise(response, status, headersString, statusText);
    if (!$rootScope.$$phase) $rootScope.$apply();
  }
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is a bug, i am not able to replicate the issue.. http://plnkr.co/edit/lRoHIJ?p=preview

Comment: Ok. I do think that !$rootScope.$$phase is the key though. And the solution is to set the useApplyAsync flag

Comment: `$rootScope.$$phase` check is made to make sure another digest is not running at the same time, before doing an `apply()`.

Comment: I know. Perhaps there is another digest running in Nicholas' code.